# Can not view the form designer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I use MS visual studio 2010. I did open designer and view the form for the same file A before. But after some small changes, I can no longer view the form designer.vb, but can only view code in designer.vb. Even if I go back to the original source, I still can not open designer!!

The error is:
The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following clsses in the file A-The base class BaseClass could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and all that projects have been built.

I checked that the file A inherits from the BaseClass. The BaseClass has a simple form and can be viewed by designer. I have a successful build. Actually, I can run the program correctly. I even tried delete bin and objects then build, but nothing helps.

I have many files that can not be opened in designer.vb. This is killing me! How can I make changes to the form then? Directly write code to designer.vb? But many suggest that do not write code directly in designer.vb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Project + Add Class to add classes to your project, don't put them in the form's source code file.  If you have to then add them to the bottom or nested inside the form class, don't put them ahead of the form class declaration.  The form class must be first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry that I do not quite get you. What is form class declaration? I did not add or delete any files in the project, so the order of previous version in which I can view designer is the same of current version.

Comment: Not adding files is the problem. Locate "Public Class Form1" in your source code where "Form1" is the form name.  Don't put anything in front of it.

Comment: Hi, let's do a concrete example. I have a file named 'Main Tabs'. It contains 3 form files. I found that ONLY the first form can be opened by designer. Is this what you mean? However, I cannot move the second form in front of the first form since 'the destination folder is the same as the source folder'. Also, it means every time I want to modify a form, I need to move it to the first?

Comment: A file does not have 3 form files.  There are two files for each form, the form.vb and the form.designer.vb file.  The form.vb file contains source code that you modify, typically by adding event handlers to it.  Use Windows Explorer and look at the directory that contains your project.  The notion of a "source code file" seems unclear to you, not sure how I can help you with that.  Consider picking up an introductory book on programming with Visual Studio from your local library.

Comment: Thanks! I know two files for each form, the form.vb and the form.designer.vb

Answer (score 3):

Click on "Show All Files" Icon at the top of the Solution Explorer, you will see the Designer.vb file

Answer (score 3):

While you are on the form code, click on View > Designer, and it will showup.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem came about when I put the form into a namespace and then took it out. The FrmXYZ.vb lost its proper build information in the project file. To fix it, I right clicked on the project in the Solution Explorer, selected "unload", and then, "edit". I searched for my form by name. First, I found a compile section about FrmXYZ.Designer.vb. This looks like the following:

```
<Compile Include="Forms\FrmXYZ.Designer.vb">
   <DependentUpon>FrmXYZ.vb</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

This was all good. Then next section was for the form file, FrmXYZ.vb. This was my problem. It read,

```
<Compile Include="Forms\FrmXYZ.vb" />
```

I changed it to the following to make visual studio know it was a form:

```
<Compile Include="Forms\FrmXYZ.vb">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Then I saved the file, closed the file, right clicked on the project, and selected, "reload project".

Problem solved (for me).

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, to solve it, run the program with this command to clear all of the options to skip loading added to VSPackages:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /ResetSkipPkgs
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try doing this:

- Close all the UI design pages
- Clean Solution
- Build Solution
- Open the desired UI design pages

This might or might not help but it certainly resolved the same issue in my project.

Answer (score 1):

I too had a situation in which I had xxx.Designer.vb, xxx.resx, and xxx.vb showing in the Solution for my Project. To fix this, I backed up my Solution/Project (Very Very Important), then I deleted the 3 xxx files found in my Solution Explorer for my Project. I then selected and copied the 3 xxx files from my backup and pasted them using Windows Explorer into the folder for my project. (make sure the folder you paste to is the folder shown in your Solution. After the paste I went back into the Project, then to the folder where the original xxx files where located, right clicked on that folder and clicked on Add - Existing Item. Then clicked ONLY on the xxx.vb file. Fixed. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ANY other classes in the ???Form.vb code, then make SURE they are defined AFTER the Form class.  This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I finally can view form in designer by doing this:

In my form_designer.vb,

Exsiting code:

Inherits Base_Class   'Base_Class is defined in my project

Change to:

Inherits Form         'Form is defined by windows

Then I can view form in designer!!!

Of course, I can not build files successfully since the inheritence is not correct. But I can first edit in form_designer, and then change back to 'Inherits Base_Class' and build or compile

Comment: Try this to help you

#If DEBUG Then  
Public Class BaseGRIDForm
#Else
Public MustInherit Class BaseGRIDForm
#End If

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, although my problem was because I obfuscated my project file. After deobfuscation, and rebuilding, it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

if you no can view the design but only the code, then
close VS go to your project directory, find the form in there, open it in any text editor and add the class name as public at the top for example

```
Public Class FrmSettings

End Class
```

that's it, now you can view the form in VS design

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem is that VB saves an extra file in a folder which is DIFFERENT TO THE ONE YOU USED TO SAVE YOUR FORMS

Do the following:

1. Open VB with nothing loaded
2. Go to File -> Open -> project/solution (drop menu in the top left corner)
3. VB will show you a folder different to the one in which you have your files. One of the folders shown will have the same name as the project you saved originally (example: Project1). Double-click in that folder to open it. You will see a *.sln file named after your project (example: Project1.sln). Double click on it to open it
4. Now you the Design View of the form will be shown!!!

KEY CONCEPT: Open the *.sln file (xxx.sln) instead of the xxx.Designer.vb, xxx.resx, and xxx.vb files!!! The xxx.sln file is located in a DIFFERENT DIRECTORY (not the same as xxx.Designer.vb, xxx.resx, xxx.vb).

In my PC that misterious directory is: 
C:\Users\Gabriel Personal\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects

Good luck guys!!!!

Answer (score 0):

At first, I apologize for my bad english.

This worked for me:

If you add an empty form to your project, you can double clik on it, and you can see the following:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

You can't see that code in the other form, probably because this class have disspeared (can't explain why)

Simply restore this class, changing the Form Name in class definition. Then, you can see the designer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, (and about VS 2010), however I just had the same problem in VS 2017 and a Google search led me here.
This problem can also occur in VS 2017 if you try to open an project from an older VS without going through the upgrade/conversion process.  For example, if you tell VS 2017 to open the Folder instead of opening a Solution or Project.
I noticed when opening it as a Folder, VS 2017 tries to arrange things logically.  You can even run the program (at least I could, in this case it was a VB console app written in VS 2010).  I could see the Code / code view by double clicking the Form.VB file, but no combination would allow me to see the Form designer.  The solution was to exit and re-open as an existing Solution.  This led through the proper conversion steps and now I can see the Form / form designer as well as the code. Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this thread might be old but just in case someone will have the same problem in due time, here is the solution.

1. In solution explorer, click "yourformname.Designer.vb" to display code layout of the missing form designer, this will show in the left pane (vs17).
2. This time around double click the same form which is missing a designer as in step 1, this will show an empty code window in the left pane.
3. In the empty code window, type the following declaration: Public Class "yourformname", and hit the Enter key on your keyboard. By doing this, an ending match End Class will be added below automatically.

Boom, there you have your designer back. Save your edits and remember to vote as answered if it worked for you. Anyone still having trouble feel free to respond here and I be happy to solve it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to View and click on Solution Explorer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

some say restarting the pc solves it.
recommended save backup files before

Go to `yourDisk:\%UserProfile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\YourProject\YourProject`

Form1.Designer
`View > Other > Other Windows Solution Explorer` Or hotkey `CTRL+R`

Rename or copy all code `Form1.Designer.vb`, save `Form1.vb`. (two files)

open project (solution open stand alone)
isso vai aparecer o Form1.vb[Design]
in `form1.vb` remove all content (empty) this is remove errors
paste all code only `Form1.Designer.vb`